# spring microservices multiple tasks handle

Tags: java, spring, microservices

I've a question related to microservices world. Let's assume I've two microservices, microservice A does a request to microservice B. Microservice B perform some "long" operations and makes a request to another microservice C. In result microservice A waits for result from microservice B. How to handle such a long operation if the microservice A is "connected" to front end service, where user initiates the operation and waits for the result of that operation.

Is there any good way to handle long-running tasks in those microservices? What would you suggest to me with that case to be the most efficient and scalable in Spring boot? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's one of the hardest problems with microservices. Do some research on transactions and transaction management. Other than that - easiest you can do - capture run id for user request and have user poll for the result of this run id and return result once it's ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a high-level, let's segregate the API calls in two major types

1. Synchronous
2. Asynchronous

**Synchronous**

This is an ideal situation implemented using `RestTemplate`, `WebClient` , `FeignClient` etc where in your Microservice A would wait for response from Microservice B.

Ideal for quick operations and covers majority use case

**Asynchronous**

As @taleodor mentioned, the other way would be to implement an `async` call to other Microservice, which would only return a `Run id` or `Acknowledgement id` to indicate the long running process started. To get status of that process, you may think of implementing it through a `Message queue` such as `ActiveMQ` or `Apache Kafka` which works on the concept of producer/consumer or `Publisher/subscriber (pub/sub)` where in your long running microservice will publish the event once completed, and Microservice A or B will subscribe to that event and read the response !

Apart of message queues, your Microservice A can also implement a `scheduled task` to check for progress completion or resource updation based on how to implement it !